# Filtering Pivot Table Items is too slow

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Code to filter pivot table is running very slowly. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Originally I used the macro recorder to set the filter on the pivot field. It worked well enough and ran very quickly, unfortunately, it requires listing all items I wish to hide. Anytime a new item is added I have to update the code.

So I did some research and came up with the code below. Which works, however, it takes quite sometime to run.

```
Sub PivotFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim pItem As PivotItem
Dim pTable As PivotTable

Set pTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

For Each pItem In pTable.PivotFields("AnalystID").PivotItems
    Select Case pItem.Caption
        Case "ANALYST1", "ANALYST2", "ANALYST3"
            pItem.Visible = True
        Case Else
            pItem.Visible = False

    End Select
Next pItem

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I expected it to be almost instant as there are only 20 items. (Later I noticed there are actually over 100 as there are several items in the table with no supporting data).

In reality it is quite slow and would almost be easier to just do it manually -- almost.

Comment: Are you sure ? I just tested your code and it ran in less than a second. Did you try to reset Microsoft Excel ? make sure you don't have any other open instances of Excel

Comment: Yes -- I added a timer code to the macro just now and it took 80.55 seconds to execute.

Keep in mind this is a rather large pivot table. There are ~35,000 rows and 55 columns in the source table.

Comment: I've continued on my quest to figure out why this code is taking so long to run but I have yet to come up with a resolution. I think it may have to do with they there are several cached items that are no longer visible requiring it to cycle through 100 or so rather than the 15 or so items that I can see. But even that doesn't seem to account for hanging up for 80 seconds.